# How to create a custom double-click event for a Button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, double-click

I'm developing in C# on the .NET Framework. I already have an event on Button which happens on one click. I also want to have an event on Double Click for the same Button.

How do I create Double click event on Button? I tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, true);
this.button1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(button1_DoubleClick);

private void button1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    MessageBox.Show("You are in the Button.DoubleClick event.");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? What is the specific error? Runtime error? Compile error?

Comment: When I click on the button ... MessageBox doesn't show...

Comment: @SpeksETC I'd expect it to be a compile error, as the event isn't declared on the `Button` class...

Comment: For future reference, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx) for the `Control.DoubleClick` event contains a helpful reference table, indicating how the various controls handle (or don't handle) that event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Button` control (assuming you're in a winforms app) does not support double click as a native event. You would need to create your own control, perhaps by inheriting from the framework provided button, and listen for two clicks within the relevant time, before firing your `DoubleClick` event.

Comment: In addition to this answer, the `this.SetStyle` that your code is doing applies to the **`Form`** your button is hosted on, not the button itself. In order for that to work, you'll have to subclass the `Button` control in your own custom class, set this style, and raise the `DoubleClick` event, as Rowland explains.