# How to implement double click to a button in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

how to implement double click event for a button in C# window application

**strong text**

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397672/how-to-create-a-custom-double-click-event-for-a-button

Comment: What is this **strong text**????

Comment: Are you asking how to raise the event or how to handle it?

Comment: how to implement the event

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler

```
btn.doubleClick += btn_doubleClick;
```

Then, define

```
private void btn_doubleClick ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
       // do stuff

}
```